# how to implement my constructor in a class which inherits from Command.php

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, command

Working with symfony2.3.4 and PHP5.6.3

I´m implementing a command of my own, well it actually does basically the same as **doctrine:generate:entity** only with some customization of mine.

I'm stuck trying to implement the constructor method in my class **OwnEntityCommand.php** which extends from **GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand** class which follows a line of upward inheritance until it reaches **Command.php**.

The constructor in that last class looks like this:

```
public function __contruct($name = null) {  
    $this->definition = new InputDefinition();  
    $this->ignoreValidationErrors = false;  
    $this->applicationDefinitionMerged = false;  
    $this->applicationDefinitionMergedWithArgs = false;  
    $this->aliases = array();  

    if(null !== $name){  
        $this->setName($name);  
    }  
    $this->configure();  

    if($this->name){  
        throw new \LogicException('The command name cannot be empty.');
    }
}
```

and the one I need in mine is supposed to look like this:

```
public function __construct(Filesystem $filesystem, RegistryInterface $registry){  
    $this->filesystem = $filesystem;  
    $this->registry = $registry;  
}
```

and the only attrs in my class being:

```
private $filesystem;  
private $registry;
```

when I try to run the command it throws:

[InvalidArgumentException]
Command "own:entity" is not defined.

do not know how to implement my own constructor without conflicting with the parent's(which I think is what's happening)

if need more data or code, just tell me

UPDATE:

```
protected function configure() {
$this
        ->setName('own:entity')
        ->setAliases(array('generate:own:entity'))
        ->setDescription('Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle')
        ->addOption('entity', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The entity class name to initialize (shortcut notation)', 'UserBundle:TestEntity')
        ->addOption('fields', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The fields to create with the new entity')
        ->addOption('format', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Use the format for configuration files (php, xml, yml, or annotation)', 'annotation')
        ->addOption('with-repository', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Whether to generate the entity repository or not');
```

}

Comment: can you post the full namespace and class name?

Comment: @Matteo **namespace CC\UserBundle\Command;** and **class OwnEntityCommand extends GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand**.
Is this it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to override the configure function in order to change the name command like this:

```
class OwnEntityCommand extends GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('own:entity')
            ->setAliases(array('entity:own'))
            ->setDescription('Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle')
            ->addOption('entity', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The entity class name to initialize (shortcut notation)')
            ->addOption('fields', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The fields to create with the new entity')
            ->addOption('format', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Use the format for configuration files (php, xml, yml, or annotation)', 'annotation')
            ->setHelp(<<<EOT
The <info>%command.name%</info> task generates a new Doctrine
entity inside a bundle:
<info>php %command.full_name% --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post</info>
The above command would initialize a new entity in the following entity
namespace <info>Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog\Post</info>.
You can also optionally specify the fields you want to generate in the new
entity:
<info>php %command.full_name% entity:own --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post --fields="title:string(255) body:text"</info>
By default, the command uses annotations for the mapping information; change it
with <comment>--format</comment>:
<info>php %command.full_name% --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post --format=yml</info>
To deactivate the interaction mode, simply use the <comment>--no-interaction</comment> option
without forgetting to pass all needed options:
<info>php %command.full_name% --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post --format=annotation --fields="title:string(255) body:text" --no-interaction</info>
This also has support for passing field specific attributes:
<info>php %command.full_name% --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Blog/Post --format=annotation --fields="title:string(length=255 nullable=true unique=true) body:text ranking:decimal(precision:10 scale:0)" --no-interaction</info>
EOT
        );
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Command/GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand.php